# Exporting Jar file in Eclipse using JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have created an app using JavaFX 2.1 and wish to export it to be tested.  This is the first "real" application I've made, so I have never done this before.  In Windows 7 with eclipse I export a runnable jar, click on it, and nothing happens.  Can someone tell me why this might be?

Comment: What was the process you executed to export a runnable jar in eclipse?

Comment: It is possible to do this with eclipse, but I found the process to be much simpler using Netbeans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Information on Packaging**

The app below was packaged using the command line [javafxpackager](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packager001.htm) tool.  JavaFX also provides [ant tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm#CIACDJHC) for packaging.  I believe you could create an ant script for packaging and run it's tasks from inside Eclipse.

The [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/) plugin provides integrated JavaFX packaging functionality by wrapping the JavaFX ant tasks.  When developing JavaFX applications with Eclipse, use of e(fx)clipse is highly recommended.

**Verifying your JavaFX Packaging**

- Extract the jar files from the jar (`jar xf <jarfile>`).
- Look at the extracted manifest (`META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`).
- If the main class in the manifest is not com/javafx/main/Main then you have packaged the app wrong.

---

```
C:\dev\javafx\willow\dist>jar xf willow.jar

C:\dev\javafx\willow\dist>type MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
JavaFX-Version: 2.1
JavaFX-Application-Class: org.jewelsea.willow.Willow
JavaFX-Class-Path: lib\image4j.jar lib\PDFRenderer-0.9.1.jar
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Main-Class: com/javafx/main/Main

C:\dev\javafx\willow\dist>java -jar willow.jar
```

For your manifest the `JavaFX-Application-Class` entry will vary and the `JavaFX-Class-Path` attribute is probably not needed.

The example jar I used can then be run from the command line using `java -jar <jarfile>`.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by the jewelsea [e(fx)clipse](http://www.efxclipse.org) provides you an export wizard which uses the ant tasks provided by JavaFX. You can find a step by step tutorial at https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1

Comment: tutorial no longer exists... did this move or is just no longer available?